# Oracle multiple case statements

Tags: sql, database, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to create 2 flags using case statement.

```
Flag1 = event_per_month
Flag2 = event_per_day
```

Below is the sample data

I am looking to create two flags based on id occurrence per day and per month.

EVENT_PER_DAY logic : If a given id and msg repeats on same day more than once then the event_per_day flag becomes "T" for the repeat event(combination of id and msg) otherwise it remains "T".

EVENT_PER_MONTH logic : If a given id and msg repeats in same month more than once then the event_per_month flag becomes "T" for the repeat event(combination of id and msg) otherwise it remains "T".

I used case statement, but the problem here is I have date as well as month column which makes it little complicated.

Here is the expected result

```
id  error_date  error_month error category  event_per_day   event_per_month
123 15-May-15 12:01:01  May-15  msg1    F   F
123 15-May-15 12:20:00  May-15  msg1    T   T
123 17-May-15 22:00:00  May-15  msg2    F   F
124 17-May-15 20:00:00  May-15  msg2    T   T
123 18-May-15 12:00:00  May-15  msg3    F   F
123 19-May-15 19:00:00  May-15  msg3    F   F
123 20-May-15 12:00:00  May-15  msg4    F   F
123 20-May-15 17:00:00  May-15  msg4    T   T
123 22-May-15 12:00:00  May-15  msg4    F   F
123 23-May-15 12:00:00  May-15  msg4    F   F
123 12-Aug-15 18:00:00  Aug-15  msg1    F   F
123 13-Aug-15 12:00:00  Aug-15  msg2    F   F
123 14-Aug-15 12:00:00  Aug-15  msg3    F   F
123 15-Aug-15 12:00:00  Aug-15  msg4    F   F
123 16-Aug-15 12:00:00  Aug-15  msg1    F   T
123 17-Aug-15 12:00:00  Aug-15  msg1    F   T
123 18-Aug-15 12:00:00  Aug-15  msg2    F   T
123 19-Aug-15 12:00:00  Aug-15  msg3    F   T
123 20-Aug-15 12:00:00  Aug-15  msg4    F   T
123 21-Aug-15 12:00:00  Aug-15  msg3    F   T
890 15-May-15 12:01:01  May-15  msg1    F   F
890 15-May-15 12:20:00  May-15  msg1    T   T
890 17-May-15 22:00:00  May-15  msg2    F   F
890 17-May-15 20:00:00  May-15  msg2    T   T
890 18-May-15 12:00:00  May-15  msg3    F   F
890 19-May-15 19:00:00  May-15  msg3    F   F
890 20-May-15 12:00:00  May-15  msg4    F   F
890 20-May-15 17:00:00  May-15  msg4    T   T
890 22-May-15 12:00:00  May-15  msg4    F   F
890 23-May-15 12:00:00  May-15  msg4    F   F
890 12-Aug-15 18:00:00  Aug-15  msg1    F   F
890 13-Aug-15 12:00:00  Aug-15  msg2    F   F
890 14-Aug-15 12:00:00  Aug-15  msg3    F   F
890 15-Aug-15 12:00:00  Aug-15  msg4    F   F
890 16-Aug-15 12:00:00  Aug-15  msg1    F   T
890 17-Aug-15 12:00:00  Aug-15  msg1    F   T
890 18-Aug-15 12:00:00  Aug-15  msg2    F   T
890 19-Aug-15 12:00:00  Aug-15  msg3    F   T
890 20-Aug-15 12:00:00  Aug-15  msg4    F   T
890 21-Aug-15 12:00:00  Aug-15  msg3    F   T
```

Comment: The results in your table don't make sense to me.  Why do the first two rows have "F" and "T"?  Please explain the logic more clearly.  What is "unique"?

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Updated the question with logic information. EVENT_PER_DAY logic : If a given id and msg repeats on same day more than once then the event_per_day flag becomes "T" for the repeat event(combination of id and msg) otherwise it remains "T".

EVENT_PER_MONTH logic : If a given id and msg repeats in same month more than once then the event_per_month flag becomes "T" for the repeat event(combination of id and msg) otherwise it remains "T".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want analytic functions:

```
select t.*,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by trunc(error_date), msg
                                     order by error_date
                                    ) = 1
             then 'F' else 'T'
        end) as event_per_day,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by error_month, msg
                                     order by error_date
                                    ) = 1
             then 'F' else 'T'
        end) as event_per_month
from table t;
```

EDIT:

The above query should be fine, but perhaps using a subquery will help:

```
select t.*,
       (case when seqnum_day = 1 then 'F' else 'T' end) as event_per_day,
       (case when seqnum_mon = 1 then 'F' else 'T' end) as event_per_month
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by trunc(error_date), msg
                                order by error_date) as seqnum_day,
             row_number() over (partition by error_month, msg
                                order by error_date) as seqnum_mon
      from table t
     ) t;
```

Comment: It is throwing invalid relational operator error. for the =1 selection in query

Comment: @DataAnalyst . . . That error doesn't really make sense, but perhaps the subquery will fix it.